# MySql Query to sum the rows and get the max value

Tags: mysql, sql, wampserver

I have a table product with sample data as below

```
product  1   2  2   3   1          
Quantity 10 15  20  10  5
```

I need to findout which product has highest quantity after summing up all the available quantity for all the products

Example: Here answer would be 15+20 = 35 is greatest so product 2 has more quantity

please help with query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select product, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
from products
group by product
order by sum_quantity desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, wanted to know if we can use max() to achieve this instead of limit?

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to use `max`. The query gets more complex using `max`